# Не работает ${} variable в WebStorm

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Создаю константу , вставляю ее в строчку , но она становится частью строки. В чем проблема. Работаю в WebStorm. Руководствуюсь материалом [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
const a = 5;
console.log('Мне исполнилось ${a} лет')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы неправильно записываете строку. Для Template literals должны использоваться обратные кавычки.

```
const a = 5;
console.log(`Мне исполнилось ${a} лет`);
```